# Calculating the eigenvalues of a given matrix, please check my results

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, wolfram-alpha

Given the matrix
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1&-0.85&0\\
    1.7&-1&0\\
    0 & 0.85 & 4
    \end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times3}$$

I am now looking for the eigenvalues of $A$. Calculating the chararacteristical polynom via $\operatorname{det}\left(A-\lambda\mathcal{I}_3\right)$ it gives me
$$ -\lambda^3+4\lambda^2 -0.445\lambda+1.78 \stackrel{!}{=}0$$

One solution is trivial ($\lambda=4$), so because of
$$-\lambda^3+4\lambda^2 -0.445\lambda+1.78 = (x-4)\cdot \left(-x^2-0.445\right)$$

Thus I just have to solve $\left(-x^2-0.445\right)=0$ which is of course
$$\lambda = \pm i\cdot\sqrt{0.445} \approx \pm i\cdot 0.667$$
In particular: The real part of those $\lambda$ is exactly $0$

Are my results correct? I am asking, because [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-0.85,0%7D;%7B1.7;-1,0%7D;%7B0,0.85,4%7D%7D) gives me
$$\lambda \approx -5.55\times10^{-17}\pm i\cdot 0.667$$
In particular: The real part of $\lambda$ is not equal to zero, but very small.

So, is this caused by rounding errors of wolfram alphas calculation only? But where could this real part come from? Or am I missing something in my solution that is causing a small real part of $\lambda$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's safe to say that the small real part is due to some sort of rounding error

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your equation of $\lambda$ is not correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results are correct. The issue is that Wolfram Alpha will use inaccurate arithmetic if you specify numbers in the dotted decimal format $x.y$, like you do with the entry $0.85$.

If you instead write $85/100$ you will get the [result you want](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-85/100,0%7D;%7B170/100;-1,0%7D;%7B0,85/100,4%7D%7D).

Comment: Interesting point, I didn't know that. Thank you.